# App links Assistant

Tags: android, applinks

App link is declared in manifest, but its working in some mobile. when we click that link. In some mobiles like asus when we click link its opening website.It doesn't ask to open with chrome or App?

Comment: how are you declaring the `app link` ?

Comment: In android manifest.xml

Comment: share the code please

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="mobile.sharekhan.com"
                    />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: and how does your link looks like ? when you call it!

Comment: it never asks me to open in my app when im clicking.it directly opens in browser. Thats it. i had given all information.